# The best way to get one single field in one line of code with ActiveRecord (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I just want to get a scalar data (like int, string, etc.) from one field of a row.
If there is no row in the DB, I want it to be a nil.

The line of code below works well if there is a row:

```
User.select(:email).where(***).first.email
```

But there isn't, it will raise "NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass".

So I must use ActiveSupport's "try" method.

```
User.select(:email).where(***).first.try(:email)
```

Or I must use pluck + Array#first instead.

```
User.select(:email).where(***).pluck(:email).first
```

But both of these two codes are a little bit lengthy to me.

Is there any better way to do this? If there is an interface like below, I'll be very happy.

```
User.where(***).field(:email)
# => returns "abc@example.com" or nil
```

Comment: FYI, the `select` and `pluck` should be redundant, so you can remove the `select` portion to shorten it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
(user = User.select(:email).where(***).first) && (user.email)
```

this will return either the email address of the user, or nil if there is no user.

Comment: Thank you Max, but using try or pluck looks simpler for me than this.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one row then you should use `find_by`. So you can refactor you code like this.

```
User.find_by(***).try(:email)
```